# How can I get the width of the table header and have the same size as the table cell in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two seperates tables: one for the header and one for the content. This is my table with only headers:

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered >
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="header-length">This is header one</th>            
          <th class="header-length">short</th>      
          <th class="header-length">X</th>            
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And this is my second table with the content

```
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered>
    <tbody>       
     <tr>     
     <td>This content must align with header one</td>
     <td>very short</td>
      <td>Icon</td>
     </tr>          
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want the `width` of the header to align the content via *JQuery* I have used this selector to get the property

```
$('.header-length').width;
```

The header of the table cell must have the same width as the content whats inside `<td>`

How can I get the width of the `th` property to have the same width as the `td` with JQuery?

Comment: Why do you have two tables if they have to share width? Just add the `<thead>` and `<tbody>` into one table and they'll automatically take the same width.

Comment: The problem is I it will be a fully dynamic table with data from the backend. Also I get fixed headers problems when I use one table.

Comment: Could you please explain further how it being dynamic data complicates using one table? And fixed headers? The reason I ask is that I had similar issues in the past, but using thead , tbody and tfoot + some styling actually fixed them.

Comment: The headers and will be dynamic from a database. I need a calculation to get the width of the header and the cell. The table cell must have a same size as the table header.

Comment: Note that creating tables like this will confuse people who use screen readers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`width` is a function.

You can apply loop to get width of each `th`.

```js
$('.header-length').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).width());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-length">This is header one</th>
      <th class="header-length">short</th>
      <th class="header-length">X</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

--Edit--

```js
const thWidthArr = [...document.querySelectorAll('.header-length')].map(th => th.offsetWidth);

const table2 = document.querySelectorAll('table')[1];

table2.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((td, i) => {
  td.style.width = thWidthArr[i] + 'px';
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header-length">This is header one</th>
      <th class="header-length">short</th>
      <th class="header-length">X</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This content must align with header one</td>
      <td>very short</td>
      <td>Icon</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I can see the width now how can I apply that the width of the table cell is the same as the table header?

Comment: @Fearcoder - You can iterate over the `td's` and apply the retrieved respective `th` width to it.

Comment: Thank you so much!